# Zeppelin - how to connect to spark ui when spark interpreter configured in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using zippelin with spark Interpreter configured with master = local[*]

I need to connect to spark web ui to observe the tasks and the execution DAG. does zippelin provide access to spark web ui with the above configuration?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Local mode means the spark UI will be accessible on the same host as Zeppelin, and unless the UI port is taken (or configured explicitly), UI will use the default 4040 port. So, for example, if Zeppelin's host is `10.0.0.2`, try `http://10.0.0.2:4040`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am running weppelin on localhost, I can now access the spark web ui indeed on http://localhost:4040

Comment: great, posting as an answer for future readers. Feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local mode means the spark UI will be accessible on the **same host** as Zeppelin, and unless the UI port is taken (or configured explicitly), UI will use the default 4040 port.

So, for example, if Zeppelin's host is `localhost`, try http://localhost:4040